# How to enable [Authorize] on TestController on IdentityServer4 for purpose of Claim CRUD Controller

Tags: identityserver4

Using OIDC Client from [here](https://github.com/jmurphzyo/Angular2OidcClient).
And demo server from [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo) and [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity).

I have the following controller on the IdentityServer itself:

```
[Route("api/Test")]
//[Authorize]
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var claims = User.Claims.Select(c => new { c.Type, c.Value });
        return new JsonResult(claims);
    }
}
```

If I comment out both `[Authorize]` attributes, I reach the TestController.

If I use just `[Authorize]`, I get the following error:

> GET http://localhost:5000/api/Test  dashboard:1  XMLHttpRequest cannot
>   load http://localhost:5000/api/Test.  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.  Origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 500.

And if I just use `[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` I get:

> GET http://localhost:5000/api/Test  dashboard:1  XMLHttpRequest cannot
>   load http://localhost:5000/api/Test.  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.  Origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.  The response
>   had HTTP status code 500. dashboard:1  XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:5000/api/Test.  Redirect from
>   'http://localhost:5000/api/Test' to
>   'http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FTest' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is
>   disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

The code I use to call the Endpoint from the OIDC client is:

```
  test() {
   this.authService.mgr.getUser()
     .then(user => {
      //  this.http.get('https://api.identityserver.io/identity', 
      this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/Test', 
       { headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': `${user.token_type} ${user.access_token}`}) })
         .subscribe(res => {
           console.log(res.json());
         });
     });
 }
```

I am able to successfully call https://api.identityserver.io/identity with this.

This is my CorsPolicyHelper:

```
public class DemoCorsPolicy : ICorsPolicyService
{
    public Task<bool> IsOriginAllowedAsync(string origin)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

And this is where its called form Startup:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
...
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();
...
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.GetClients())
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

            services.AddTransient<ICorsPolicyService, DemoCorsPolicy>();
        }
```

Ultimate goal is to perform CRUD operations on permissions/claims.  I am currently stuck on this seemingly trivial task of having an Authorization protected controller :/

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately since I am able to to use `[Authorize]` successfully outside IdentityServer4, I decided to separate Authorization from Authentication and create an Authorization server which provides for separation of concerns.